# Se me cierra la app

Tags: java, android, xml

Se ejecuta la app pero presiono un botón se cierra la aplicación.
codigo JAVA:

```
package com.example.calculadora.calculadorabasica;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8,
                btn9, btnpun, btnres, btnsum, btnrest, btnmul, btndiv, btnret;
        EditText edtsuma, edtconca;
        double numero1, numero2, resultado;
        String operador;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            btnret = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_buno);
            btn0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_0);
            btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
            btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
            btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_3);
            btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_4);
            btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_5);
            btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_6);
            btn7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_7);
            btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_8);
            btn9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_9);
            btnpun = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_punto);
            btnres = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_igual);
            btnsum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_suma);
            btnrest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_resta);
            btnmul = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_prod);
            btndiv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_div);
            edtsuma = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);

            btn0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                    edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + "0");
                }
            });

            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                    edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + "1");

                    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + "2");
                        }
                    });

                    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + "3");
                        }
                    });

                    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + "4");
                        }
                    });

                    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + "5");
                        }
                    });

                    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + "6");
                        }
                    });

                    btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            edtsuma.setText(edtsuma.getText().toString() + "7");
                        }
                    });

                    btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + "8");
                        }
                    });

                    btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + "9");
                        }
                    });

                    btnpun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            edtsuma.setText(edtconca.getText().toString() + ".");
                        }
                    });

                    btnres.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            numero2 = Double.parseDouble(edtconca.getText().toString());
                            if(operador.equals("+")){
                                edtsuma.setText("");
                                resultado = numero1 + numero2;
                            }
                            if(operador.equals("-")){
                                edtsuma.setText("");
                                resultado = numero1 - numero2;
                            }
                            if(operador.equals("*")){
                                edtsuma.setText("");
                                resultado = numero1 * numero2;
                            }
                            if(operador.equals("/")){
                                edtsuma.setText("");
                                if(numero2 != 0){
                                    resultado = numero1 / numero2;
                                }else {
                                    edtsuma.setText("Infinito");
                                }
                            }
                            edtsuma.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
                        }
                    });

                    btnsum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            operador = "+";
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            numero1 = Double.parseDouble(edtconca.getText().toString());
                            edtsuma.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                    btnrest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            operador = "-";
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            numero1 = Double.parseDouble(edtconca.getText().toString());
                            edtsuma.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                    btnmul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            operador = "*";
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            numero1 = Double.parseDouble(edtconca.getText().toString());
                            edtsuma.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                    btndiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            operador = "/";
                            edtconca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtsuma);
                            numero1 = Double.parseDouble(edtconca.getText().toString());
                            edtsuma.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                    btnret.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            numero1 = 0;
                            numero2 = 0;
                            edtsuma.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

CODIGO XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.calculadora.calculadorabasica.MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:id="@+id/edtsuma"
            android:textSize="45sp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_ce"
                android:layout_width="192dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="DEL"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_buno"
                android:layout_width="192dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="AC"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_7"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_8"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_9"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_div"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="/"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_4"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_5"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_6"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_prod"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="*"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_1"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_2"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_3"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_resta"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_punto"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="."
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_0"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_igual"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="="
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_suma"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Que error te da en la consola

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper ninguno, corro el programa, se ejecuta, se abre la app, presiono un botón y muestra un mensaje que la app dejó de funcionar

Comment: Pero en el android estudio te tiene que dar errores en la consola

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Pero algo mas pondra, normalmente te dice en donde esta el error

Comment: @SamsungDeveloper FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.calculadora.calculadorabasica, PID: 3493
                                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btn_9'

Comment: Te falla al clicar en cualquier botón o en alguno en concreto?

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo cualquier botoón

Comment: estoy buscando el fallo, de momento prueba a quitar el `edtconca.getText().toString()` , creo que el `toString()` está de más

Comment: **Es importante que cuando preguntes agregues el mensaje desplegado en LogCat, además, si buscas en el sitio hay varias respuestas** de este problema : https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Could+not+find+method+onClick%28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está en la definición de los botones, al asignar al atributo `onClick` una función pública de la clase *MainActivity*. Ese método no existe, y al no encontrarlo da un error y cierra la aplicación.

Lo que tendrías que hacer es borrar ese atributo de las definiciones para que funcione ya que estás definiendo el onClick en todos los botones de forma programática con los métodos `setOnClickListener`. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ce"
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="DEL"
    android:textSize="40sp"
/>
```

Además, te dejo un ejemplo de uso correcto del atributo `onClick`:

**Implementación de setOnClickListener**

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myFancyMethod(v);
    }
});

// Método definido en el atributo onClick
public void myFancyMethod(View v) {
    // Haz cualquier cosa
}
```

**Implementación XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- layout elements -->
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:onClick="myFancyMethod"
/>
```

Por último te dejo una advertencia:

`android:onClick` solo funciona en API nivel 4 y siguientes, así que si usas una versión < 1.6, no puedes utilizar ese atributo.

Te dejo más información en [este post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener)